# Decomposition of a function in positive and negative parts and its integrability

Tags: proof-writing

Is it true to say that $\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|dx<\infty\Rightarrow\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)=0$?

Comment: If no, then under what conditions above statement holds

Comment: R to L implication basically say: if a function is integrable, then it integrate to $0$. Of course it won't hold... And L to R implication basically say: if a function integrate to $0$, then it's integrable. Of course, that's trivially by definition.

Comment: Whoa, not at all. Any odd, integrable function has that property. Like $f(x)={\sin x\over e^{x^2}}$

Comment: The condition you want is

$$\int_\mathbb{R}f^+=\int_\mathbb{R}f^-$$ since

$$\int_\mathbb{R} f = \int_\mathbb{R}f^+-\int_\mathbb{R}f^-$$

Comment: The answer to your new question is ALSO no. There are tons of integrable functions which have integral not $0$, take $e^{-x^2}$ for starters, or ${1\over 1+x^2}$.

Comment: @SAMEER: Maybe you meant $\int |f(x)|dx < \infty $, then $\int f(x)dx < \infty$ ?

Comment: To anyone voting this question down: I don't think it is a *bad* question. In that sense, it does not deserve voting down. It does, if OP will continnue his no-response policy, deserve to be closed, but not voted down if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is far from correct. For example, it fails for simple functions like $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$, for which $\int f(x) dx \neq 0$ despite the fact that $\int |f(x)| dx < \infty$. The implication you wrote does not hold.